# access properties in v-repeat over array from objects in vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have a json-result with 5 categories that I want to loop over with v-repeat. I use the push-method to pass the result to my vue-model.

The setup is 5 different categories to which my records belong. Each category must be shown in a different tab (I removed the category-filter on my results cause is not related to the issue).

The records are showing perfectly (v-repeat="results") and I also get 5 tabs but no values (text neither value).

console.log(this.categories) gives me an array of 5 objects from which I don't succeed to show the properties...what am I doing wrong?

I tried all kinds of things like $value, categorie:categories, ...

JSON-result from my api-call over my categories:

```
{
    status: "success",
    data: {
        results: {
            general: "Algemeen",
            metadata: "Meta-data",
            facebook: "Facebook",
            twitter: "Twitter",
            googleplus: "Google+"
        }
    }
}
```

The fetching in my Vue-file:

```
fetchCategories: function(){
    this.$http.get('/api/tokens/categories', function (response) {

        for(var prop in response.data.results) {
            this.categories.push({text: response.data.results[prop], value: prop});
        }
    });
},
```

And my view:

```
<tabs>
    <tab v-repeat="category in categories" header="@{{ category.text }}">
        <div id="@{{ category.value }}">
            <table id="@{{ category.value }}-token-list" class="data-list">
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>categorie</th>
                    <th>naam</th>
                    <th>slug</th>
                </tr>
                <tr v-repeat="results" v-class="odd: (index%2!=0)">
                    <td>@{{ id }}</td>
                    <td>@{{ category }} </td>
                    <td>@{{ name }} </td>
                    <td>@{{ slug }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </tab>
</tabs>
```

EDIT:

I do get my value when I write this:

```
@{{ categories[0].text }} or @{{ categories[0].value}}
```

EDIT 2:

it is a problem with the tab-functionality from VueStrap. When I use just a list with @{{ value }} it all work just fine

Comment: What version of VueStrap are you using. v1.0.0 is not compatible with vue 0.12.x

Comment: @Aman I am using the 0.12.x version. Fact is that it does work with a list but not with the tabs. Even when skipping VueStrap and working with the nav-tabs from bootstrap.

Comment: A fiddle would really help in diagnosing this issue. Can you create one?

Comment: @Aman here I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bflydesign/079zjxed/) If you leave out the component part in the vm you will notice the values are rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a 0.12 issue. Upgrading to 1.0.x will be the solution!